# Number to character?

Tags: c

I have created a function that is called Gift and an Admin can type a username and if the username is found in the 2d array,then a gift will be added to the total amount of the user.

The 2d array: char pin[50][7][100];

Each row contains a single user and each column contains his info like name, surname etc.
Now,the total amount of each user is located to pin[i][4]

The gift is calculated based on the length of the username.Each character of the username is 10$.For example if the username is Mary the gift would be 40$.
I have managed to calculate the amount of gift but I do not know how can I replace the initial amount(which is 0 by default) with the gift.Here is the function:

```
void Gift()
{
    printf("Enter the username of the user you want to gift: \n");
    scanf("%s", &key3);

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (j = 5; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(pin[i][5], key3) == 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; key3[i] != '\0'; ++i) ;
                gift = 10 * i;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you unable to indent your code? Is there a problem with your spacebar?

Comment: And why are you using global variables? Why not use `strlen`?

Comment: @Sterg: Why do you use a 3 dimension array ? It's insane to use/read.

Comment: I am really limited cause the proffessor asks to do these assignments with what he teaches us so ye..

Comment: @ Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant I can not input words in a 2d array.

Comment: What is `pin`? What is `key3`?

Comment: this is kinda irrelevant..I just want the result of the gift e.x 40$ to be replaced in the pin[i][4].
pin is the name of the array,key is the username which is typed by the admin to search for the username in the array.

Comment: The issue is that I can not replace a char with an int.

Comment: I, nor anybody else, has a clue to the datatypes of the gobal variables - that includes `gift` as well as those mentioned above

Comment: I already mentioned that finding the actual gift is not really a problem.I have found the right amount.The problem is to replace it in the array.

Comment: @sterg - What have you learned today? hopefully to indent your code

Comment: @Sterg - Good - hopefully at least you have learned something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes

```
for (j = 5; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(pin[i][5], key3) == 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; key3[i] != '\0'; ++i) ;
                gift = 10 * i;

            }
        }
```

- `j` can only be 5 in the loop (and it is not even used!)
- use `strlen` foir the other loop
- I assume `gift` is a character array of a suitable length

So the code can be

```
        if (strcmp(pin[i][5], key3) == 0)
        {
            sprintf(gift, "%d",  10 * strlen(keys[i]));
        }
```

Comment: Probably `snprintf` would be better

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The amount is now converted to char but I can't manage to insert it to the array.